# wxPython Resize with scrolledPanel sometimes breaks painting of buttons

Tags: python, resize, wxpython, repaint

I've got a wxPython program that uses a ScrolledPanel and it's doing something really strange on some resizes. If you drag the resize around a bit, one of the buttons will start looking messed up.

Before:
http://s7.postimage.org/stoc27517/Good_Window.png

After:
http://s9.postimage.org/s2apf38m7/Bad_Window.png

Here's the code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class TestApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.setupGUI()

    def setupGUI(self):

        #Fires on window resize
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

        self.box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.box)

        self.scrolling_window = scrolled.ScrolledPanel( self )
        self.scrolling_window.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.scrolling_window.SetupScrolling()

        self.gb = wx.GridBagSizer(5,5)
        self.scrolling_window.SetSizer(self.gb)

        self.btnOne = wx.Button(self.scrolling_window,label='One')
        self.btnTwo = wx.Button(self.scrolling_window,label='Two')

        self.gb.Add(self.btnOne, pos=(0,0), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.gb.Add(self.btnTwo, pos=(1,1), flag=wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)

        self.gb.AddGrowableCol(0)
        self.gb.AddGrowableRow(1)

        self.box.Add(self.scrolling_window,1,wx.EXPAND)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnSize(self, e):
        #This refresh shouldn't be necessary
        #self.Refresh()

        #Pass event up the chain so window still resizes
        e.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    TestApp(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The only way I could prevent this behavior was to uncomment the self.Refresh() in the OnSize method. This would essentially force a repaint on every window resize. But I don't think this should be necessary. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the downside of doing the refresh?

Comment: Well a slight performance penalty from double-refreshing, since the refresh should already be firing anyways on a resize. Though in this simple of an example the performance hit isn't a huge deal. I guess my main issue is that is just seems hack-ish. A simple layout like this should be able to handle a resize.